# PGraphics outofmemory issue  Java/Processing.org

Tags: java, processing

I am using Java/Processing.org to create a drawing application.

I need to be able to reset the PGraphics object quite a lot.
This is fine if I am only drawing rects,lines ect to the PGraphics object.
But I need to be able to draw images to it.

Is there any way to reset the PGraphics object without calling:

```
graphic=createGraphics(700, 700, JAVA2D);
```

or is there some other way around this  issue?

Here is some sample code to highlight the issue.
It should crash after about 40+ clicks...

```
PImage img;
PImage main_image;

PGraphics graphic;

void setup(){
  size(700,700);
 img=loadImage("img.png"); 
  graphic=createGraphics(700, 700, JAVA2D); 
}

void draw(){

 graphic.beginDraw();
 graphic.image(img,mouseX,mouseY,10,10); 

 graphic.endDraw();
 image(graphic,0,0);


}

void mouseClicked(){

  graphic=createGraphics(700, 700, JAVA2D); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:::
Instead of calling createGraphic each time I just call the following function:

```
graphic = setAlpha(graphic);
```

and here's the function:

```
PGraphics setAlpha(PGraphics g){
  g.loadPixels();
 for (int x = 0; x < g.width; x++ ) {
    for (int y = 0; y < g.height; y++ ) {

      // Calculate the 1D pixel location
      int loc = x + y*g.width;

  g.pixels[loc]=color(0,0);
 }  
 } 
 g.updatePixels();
 return g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PGraphics has a function that already does this: `clear()`.

From the [reference](https://processing.org/reference/clear_.html):

> Clears the pixels within a buffer. This function only works on PGraphics objects created with the createGraphics() function. Unlike the main graphics context (the display window), pixels in additional graphics areas created with createGraphics() can be entirely or partially transparent. This function clears everything in a PGraphics object to make all of the pixels 100% transparent.